# R psych package - plot weighted correlation matrix - how to reference the weights source?

Tags: r, psych

I am using the pairs.panels from the Psych package in R to create nice plots of scatterplots and the correlations for multiple variables in a data frame.

```
require(psych)

# plot correlation no weights
pairs.panels(iris[ ,1:3], 
             gap = 0,
             pch = 21,
             ellipses = TRUE,
             show.points = TRUE,
             smoother = TRUE,
             rug = FALSE,
             main = '~ Naive Correlations',
             cor = TRUE
             )
```

The help for the package indicates that weighting can be used to compute the weighted correlations ... see my attempt below

```
# weighted correlations
pairs.panels(iris[ ,1:3],
             gap = 0,
             pch = 21,
             ellipses = TRUE,
             show.points = TRUE,
             smoother = TRUE,
             rug = FALSE,
             main = '~ Weighted Correlations',
             cor = TRUE,
             wt = iris[ ,4]
             )
```

This attempt returns the error 'Error in wt[, c(1:2)] : incorrect number of dimensions'. I'm not sure why I am getting this error as I assumed that pointing at a column of weights would work - suggestion appreciated

Comment: refer to the **Note** section of the `pairs.panels`-manual: "The wt parameter allows for ... The current implementation uses the *first two columns of the weights matrix* for all analyses." That is, `pairs.panels` expects a two-column wide matrix of weights. That's also what's written in the Error statement. Note the second to last sentence in this manuals section as well: "The use of this option would be to plot the means from a statsBy analysis and then display the weighted correlations by specifying the means and ns from the statsBy run."

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example?  I'm afraid I don't understand how to prepare 'weights matrix' or what 'statsBy' is

Comment: there is an example at the `pairs.panels`-manual: the last one. `statsBy` is a method in the **psych** package to compute (e.g.) correlations within and between groups for multilevel analyses.

Comment: OK I gave that a try set xx <- statsBy(iris,"Petal.Width") and this creates a matrix - how when I use 'xx$n' as the weight I get an error "Error in xc/sqrt(w) : non-conformable arrays".  Not sure how to correct this

Comment: in the manual, they use `xx$mean` as the object `x` that is to be plotted. Your call would be `pairs.panels(xx$mean[, 1:3], Correlations', wt=xx$n)`

Comment: Tom appreciated - final working code of example above for reference of others...
require(psych)
xx <- statsBy(iris,"Petal.Width")
pairs.panels(xx$mean[ ,1:3],gap = 0,pch = 21, ellipses = TRUE,              show.points = TRUE,smoother = TRUE,rug = FALSE, main = 'Weighted Correlations',cor = TRUE,wt=xx$n)

Comment: Update -  defeat from victory it seems - this does not really work in terms of individual weighting all values by a weight variable and getting the weighted correlation - tried the above solution with 8,000+ data and the process reported an error of having too many groups - perhaps there is another R package that computes weighted correlations out there?

Comment: several do, among others the **stats** package using `cov.wt`. However, I don't really have any experience with weighted tetra-/polychoric correlations.  [Rseek](https://rseek.org/) finds `weightedCorr` in the R package [**wCorr**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wCorr/wCorr.pdf)